# On IntelliJ, how to run JDBC connection on starting Glassfish

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, intellij-idea, glassfish

In Intellij Idea 12, i'm trying to start glassfish and deploy my application.

I got that error: rg.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException. Port 1527 closed.

But when I run the same project in Netbeans, I see that Netbeans start the connection on 1527 before starting Glassfish. And the option is checked: "Enable JDBC Driver Deployment".

How can I do the same in Intellij?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That was due to the Apache derby server that wasn't running.
I need to run before the script "startNetworkServer" from derby driver to make it work